# Enter-PSSession returns PSRemotingTransportException

Tags: powershell

When I try to connect to a distant server using Enter-PSSession, I have a PSRemotingTransportException. It says that the user is either unknown or associated with a wrong password.

It works with other users, and it works with this user on other servers.

The user is in the Administrator Group of the distant server.

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Can you post the complete command and error message?